# NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString: [...] usingBlock does never stop

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

I am invoking the mentioned function and it is correctly iterating through all the matches. Though, it does not finish executing after all the matched blocks were handled. What might I be doing wrong?

The used regexp is: `/\[([^\[\{,]*(,\n)?)*\]/`

Comment: You sure this is your regex? Doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: It is formated as an Objective-C string.

Comment: I have fixed it to the normal regexp format

Comment: FailDev, what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your answer to your own question, it appears that you solved the problem by passing `NSMatchingReportCompletion`. I suspect that you may have cured a symptom rather than the disease.

I wonder if you may have accidentally passed the wrong `options` value to `enumerateMatchesInString`. For example, it's very easy to mistakenly invoke it like so:

```
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:stringToSearch
                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToSearch length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         // This is called many times, 
                         // even when there is no match!
                     }];
```

This, at first blush, looks fine, the compiler doesn't complain, but we get the undesirable behavior of the block getting called too many times, often with `result == nil`.

You can solve this problem by adding `NSMatchingReportCompletion` to the `options`, and rather than getting the block called many times, it's called just for the matches and once more upon completion. That fixes it, but it's an inelegant solution and overlooks the source of the problem.

The issue is that `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` simply is not an appropriate value for the `options` parameter of `enumerateMatchesInString` ... it's an `options` value for `regularExpressionWithPattern`). Worse, `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` just happens to be identical to `NSMatchingReportProgress`, which generates the behavior you describe.

The correct solution is to simply pass an `options` value of `0`, like below, and `enumerateMatchesInString` will be called just for matches, and not for interim progress and not upon completion:

```
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:stringToSearch
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToSearch length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         // do stuff here
                     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by passing `NSMatchingReportCompletion` as option and by setting stop to YES when the match is nil.